# Blender 2.8 curve guide forcefield and torus knot

Tags: particles, force-fields

I was just playing with blender 2.8 particle systems and I wanted to make my particles follow a curve.
I created a torus knot path using the Torus Knots+ plugin but it doesn't seems to work.
I managed to get it working with more classical curves (hand drawn bezier and nurbs) but not this one.

Is there any trick I'm not aware to get it working ?

Thanks,

Comment: A torus knot is not a curve but a mesh. It won't work as a path to follow, but it could work as a collision object. Else make a bézier curve that has the shape you are after.

Comment: Actually, there's a curve version of the torus knot plugin. Althought it also generates a surface mesh by default, you can deactivate it to only keep a poly, bezier or nurbs curve. This can be verified in edit mode. Still, the physic engine doesn't seem to recognize it as a true curve object.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found why it wasn't working as expected. In the **object data** panel, the **Path animation** must be ticked for the curve guide to work. It is ticked by default for Bézier curve but not for torus knots.